# C++11 regex matches within matches

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Is it possible to iterate through all matches including those within matches?

I'm trying to extract from my string `oook outside` substrings starting with `o` that end with a different character: i.e. `oook`, `ook`, `ok` and `ou`.

I would think the following code would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "oook outside";
    regex e("o+[a-z]");

    sregex_iterator it(s.begin(), s.end(), e);
    sregex_iterator it_end;

    while (it != it_end) {
        cout << it->str() << endl;
        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead, it prints just `oook` and `ou`.

Comment: That regular expression basically results in the following: Find something that starts with an 'o'. The next character can be any number of 'o's as long as it ends or has a single alphabetic character. But I think what you want, is a **lookahead** or a **Lookbehind** I think. If you want to match inside the match [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If you just want the entire string as long as it starts with an 'o', just add a `*` to the `[a-z]` so it's `[a-z]*`

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading into the reference but it's quite difficult for me to understand.  Any chance you could provide a code sample on how I would use a **lookaround**?

Answer (score 2):

Match it all, but consume nothing.
Engines will bump up the position by 1 on each match that does not
consume a character.

To see the match, wrap it into a capture group.

`(?=(o+[a-z]))`

Expanded

```
 (?=
      ( o+ [a-z] )                  # (1)
 )
```

If the engine *doesn't* bump it along, then you can always manually consume 1.
To match it all but consume 1 use:

`(?=(o+[a-z]))o`

Expanded

```
 (?=
      ( o+ [a-z] )                  # (1)
 )
 o
```

Both are equivalent. Get the results from capture group 1.

Matches

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
oook  

--------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 3 ) 
ook  

--------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 2 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 2 , len 2 ) 
ok  

--------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 5 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 5 , len 2 ) 
ou
```

Comment: Use `o+` not `oo*`.

Comment: I tried replacing my regex pattern string `"o+[a-z]"` with `"(?=(o+[a-z]))"`. Now my code just runs printing empty newlines indefinitely.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong but the lookforward looks very helpful indeed and I'm just trying to figure how to incorporate it into my original code.

Comment: @lissachen - The whole idea is that even though there was a _match_, capture group 0 (the overall match) is empty. You won't be able to see that. However, you can access the sub-match, i.e. group 1 `$1` and print that out. Change the iterator syntax, not sure but it could be `it->[1].str()`

Comment: Or, it's something like `cout << (*it)[1].first << endl;` where `[1]` is sub-match 1 (group 1).

Comment: Hmm... `it->size()` is returning 2 and I'm printing `oook` and an empty string with `for (int i = 0; i < it->size(); i++) cout << it->str(i) << endl; `. Getting closer but still have to figure out how to adjust my `sregex_iterator`s as I'm printing `oook` and the empty string in an infinite loop.

Comment: @lissachen - If it won't bump along by itself, do it manually `(?=(o+[a-z]))o`  But, C++::regex gets it's origins from _boost::regex_  which does bump along. Engines that _don't_ do that are susceptible to crashing as it enters into infinite loops, which is undesirable.

Comment: I guess there is always `string str((*it)[1].first, (*it)[1].second)` if you need to make a string out of it. `(*it)[1].first` is just a (char*) which cout should know what to do with. Remember that `dereferencing a regex_iterator object it yields a const reference to a match_results` but, you still have to _index_ the sub-expressions.

Comment: And, might want to change `it++;` to `++it;` not sure why but it shows that way in some boost examples.

Comment: `++it` over `it++` usually matters if you are removing from an iterated set.

Comment: @sln can you explain how the `o` at the back of `(?=(o+[a-z]))o` manually bumps along the regex?  I couldn't find documentation saying C++ does not bump automatically or documentation on how to bump a regex along.  And why is it the character `o`?

Comment: "Matches within matches" are but sequential matches.  Suppose a pattern matches at positions 3 through 7, 3 through 11, and 8 through 14.  The second is clearly "within" the first, but that doesn't matter: just based upon their starting offsets and lengths, they can procedurally be iterated across sequentially.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner - Though that doesn't mean sequential capture groups correspond to sequential string positions.  Consider something like this `(?:.*?(?:(?(1)(?!))\b(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\b|(?(2)(?!))with (\w+))){2}`

Comment: @lissachen - Matching something that advances the current position is probably better than the phrase _manually bumps the current_ position. Assertions don't advance the current position because externally, they return true/false, that's their function. So we just match the `o` which _consumes_ a character and advances the current position by 1. Internal to assertions, expressions are just like any other's. So we just capture some stuff. The result is we advanced the position by 1 but captured more than 1. The _match_ however, the thing that IS the match, group 0, only matched one character.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
int main() {
    string s = "oook outside";
    smatch m;
    regex e("(?=(o+[a-z]))o");  // "o+[a-z]";

    while (regex_search(s, m, e)) {
        cout << m[1] << endl;
        s = m.suffix();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: It's always better to use _regex_search_ than regex_iterator. The iterator encapsulates the target string, smatch and the basic_regex. Through overload `++` it just sets the 's'  target string pointer to m[0].second which becomes the start of the next search. Also, the overload `*it` just returns a reference to smatch, ('m' in your example). Stay away from using _suffix_ or _prefix_ stuff, stick to using smatch indexing to access values. Change it to `s = m[0].second;` Try to use boost::regex instead of C++11, even though the TR1 came from boost, it's crippled using EcmaScript.

Comment: Where as boost::regex has Perl as well. boost::regex is also modifiable since the source code is available. And, you can include the sparse regex source into your project, compile it under _your_ settings and not have to load/include their huge library.

Comment: For a better understanding of _regex_iterator_ see it's section here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html.